# Using scipy linprog

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

Let's say I have the following problem:

1. objective function `c1x1 + c2x2`  (we need to minimize it)
2. `-x1 + x2 <= 0`
3. `0 <= x1 <= 3`
4. `0 <= x2 <= 2`

We also assume that `c1 = 1` and `c2 = -0.5` and another constrain has been added `c1x1 + c2x2 = P, were P = -1,0,1`.

What is the right way to use `linprog` in order to solve this problem?
is `bounds` refer to lower bounds?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by your equality constraint? Surely, constraining the same expression to equal three different things renders your program infeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the issue about the impossible equality constraint mentioned in the comment, we only have to refer to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html):

```py
A_ub @ x <= b_ub
A_eq @ x == b_eq
lb <= x <= ub
```

Here, `lb` is 0 by default, so you don't have to bother with the lower bounds at all, and your problem boils down to `c = [1, -0.5]`, `A_ub = [[-1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]`, and `b_ub = [0, 3, 2]`:

```py
In [57]: linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub)                                                                          
Out[57]: 
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 9.37460773860971e-11
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([7.91922932e-11, 3.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1.08299862e-10, 2.91075683e-11])
```

That is, up to numerical issues, the optimal solutions is `x1 = x2 = 0` (which is also fairly obvious: The only way to get a negative objective would be let `x2` be positive, but your first constraint would then require that `x1` be at least as large as `x2`, which in turn causes your objective to become positive).

Comment: In case the lower bound is not zero, how do I use `lb` when calling the function? I assume it relates to `bounds` arg. can you please show me how?

Comment: Yes, as per the documentation "Note that by default `lb = 0` and `ub = None` unless specified with `bounds`." Moreover, the documentation for `bounds` specifies that you should provide a tuple for each variable, e.g. something like `[(-5, 10), (-4, 5)]` to specify that `-5 <= x1 <= 10` and `-4 <= x2 <= 5`. Alternatively, lower bounds  can be encoded in `A_ub` directly by flipping the sign.